# How to set attributes of a function when defining this function?

Tags: python, function, syntax, attributes

We know that one can set attributes of a function like this:

```
def foo():
    pass
foo.__setattr__("nameattr","myname")
```

Now, I'd like to set it like this:

```
def foo():
    #self.__setattr__("nameattr","myname")
    pass
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: You could do: `def foo(): foo.nameattr = myname`. But then the attribute will be set everytime you call the function. Moreover if you do not call the function, the attribute will not be set!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the assignment inside the body of the function:

```
def foo():
    foo.nameattr = value
```

Or:

```
def foo():
    setattr(foo, "nameattr", value)
```

There is no need to explicitly call `__setattr__`.

Note however that this will set the attribute everytime you call the function, moreover you *must* call the function for this to work:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> def foo():
...     global a
...     foo.a = a
... 
>>> foo.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> foo()
>>> foo.a
1
>>> a = 2
>>> foo.a
1
>>> foo()
>>> foo.a
2
```

As you can see the attribute is not set if you don't call the function before accessing it. Moreover at everycall the value could change.

If you want to just set the attribute once you could use a decorator.
It would be nice to be able to just use `partial` with `setattr`, but unfortunately `setattr` uses positional-only arguments. But we can write our own wrapper:

```
from functools import partial

def set_attribute(object, name, value):
    setattr(object, name, value)

@partial(set_attribute, name="a", value=1)
def foo():
    pass

print(foo.a)  # -> 1
```

Comment: Thanks,i had considered to use decorator or metaclass .Even had i considered that can function inherit like class.Pardon me, i'm just a beginner and have some fantasy.

Answer (score 0):

Functions do not have instances, they just take inputs (or no inputs) and compute. Do this as a class:

```
In [7]: class Foo(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.__setattr__("nameattr", "myname")
   ...:         

In [8]: foo = Foo()

In [9]: foo.nameattr
Out[9]: 'myname'
```

This normal way to do this is:

```
In [10]: class Foo(object):
   ....:     def __init__(self, name):
   ....:         self.name = name
   ....:         

In [11]: foo = Foo("John")

In [12]: foo.name
Out[12]: 'John'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But that not what i actually want.In fact,when using flask,i want make a response function to declare it's own url attribute by itself.so that  the project is easier to be separated.